# Failing to install R oligo and RCurl packages on Linux CentOS 7

Tags: r, linux, rcurl, bioconductor

I am trying to install the Bioconductor [oligo](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/oligo.html) R package on my laptop where I have Linux CentOS 7.
It cannot be installed through the common Bioconductor installation commands because it says that RCurl was installed for anoter Rversion and needs to be reinstalled.

I tried to install it through the command: `install.packages("RCurl")`
but unfortunately it did not work.

Here's the log:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RCurl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/davide/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
  libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed

Execution halted ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/davide/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RCurl’

The downloaded source packages are in   ‘/tmp/RtmpAcmmPE/downloaded_packages’ Warning message: In install.packages("RCurl") :   installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Looks like libiconv is missing. This is probably a part of the `libcurl-devel` package, which can be installed from terminal using `sudo yum install libcurl-devel`

Comment: Thanks @bob. I tried to reinstall it but it says `Package libcurl-devel-7.29.0-51.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/22213/) old thread from the bioconductor issues page.

Comment: if you google the issue - using "error package namespace failed RCurl" and "cannot open shared library", there are a bunch of links that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install the RCurl and oligo packages in R by installing miniconda and using its R version.

Here's what I did:

1. I downloaded the miniconda installer from their [website](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) (my
   case was [64-bit (bash installer)](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh))
2. I made the file executable and then executed it. On the shell terminal, I ran:
   `chmod 777 ./Downloads/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

   `./Downloads/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`
3. I replied yes to all the questions miniconda was prompting me.
4. Once miniconda was installed, I ran R: `R`
5. I then reinstalled RCurl: `install.packages("RCurl");`
6. I then installed oligo:

   `if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))`

   `install.packages("BiocManager")`

   `BiocManager::install("oligo", version = "3.8")`

Everything worked fine to me this way. I hope it can help other people!